# MailChimp & Sprout Forms

Tags: plugins, form, plugin-sproutforms

I am using Sprout Forms for my contact forms and I want to integrate the MailChimp subscribe plugin but it looks like the MC Subscribe plugin needs to have `name="mcvars[FIRSTNAME]"` on the input fields and Sprout Forms needs `name="fields[LASTNAME]"`.

Also, they have different hidden fields for the action:

**MailChimp Subscribe**

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="mailchimpSubscribe/list/Subscribe">
```

**Sprout Forms**

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="sproutForms/entries/saveEntry">
```

Has anyone managed to integrate the two so people can choose to subscribe to a list while also using the power of Sprout Forms?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, this may be a bit challenging to pull of with Sprout Forms v1.1.0

We do have several features and improvements in the works that will help you achieve this in the future though, including:

- Full control over customizing the template HTML
- The ability to customize the value of the name="" inputs
- The option to submit form data to third-party URLs
- Control over hidden fields

While I don't have a release date for you — the features above are currently under development.

I'll plan to revisit and update this post once we release those features.

Comment: Hi Ben, on a similar note is it possible to automatically import a contact form submission email into Campaign Monitor?

Comment: +1 please Ben. Would be GREAT to be able to submit selected field values to a Campaign Monitor or MailChimp list :)